# ng-if statement works one way but not another, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements

When I write my ng-if statement like this...

`ng-if="$state.params.Step != vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 2 && vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 1"`

it doesn't work at all. I thought the above was just a shorter form of...

`ng-if="$state.params.Step != vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 2 && $state.params.Step != vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 1"`

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to repeat myself if I can help it.

Comment: `a != b && a != c` is not the same as `a != b && c`; the latter specifies a different - and valid on its own - logical expression.

Comment: no need to repeat if you do lengthy conditionals in controller instead of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is not repeating yourself. :-)

Angular evaluates expressions like JavaScript does (I think it actually uses JavaScript to do it, but I haven't checked under the covesr). JavaScript, like nearly all the languages with syntax derived from B (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, ...) don't have a `x != a && b` or `x != a || b`, you have to spell it out: `x != a && x != b` or `x != a || x != b`. That's just how it is.

The only reason you don't get an *error* is that JavaScript has type coercion, and so `x != a && b` evaluates to `(x != a) && b`, which ends up being `true && b` or `false && b`. `b` is then coerced to boolean according to the usual rules (anything *falsy* ends up being `false`, everything else ends up `true`). (The *falsy* values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-if="$state.params.Step != vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 2 && vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 1"
```

This is basically saying:

```
($state.params.Step != vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 2) &&
 vm.$localStorage.builder[$state.params.ID].Data.Steps.length - 1
```

This compares then `&&`s the result with the last number. Valid; almost certainly not what you want.

This logic should almost certainly be moved out of the `ng-if` where it's almost impossible to read.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops, yep.